# Can you give stolen property back to the thief?

Tags: united-states, property, theft, mail

This question is inspired by this [video](https://youtu.be/tJI2e8V1tNI?si=Lu8edcZ5RWWKH6rt) by the lock picking lawyer, who given his name I'm assuming knows a thing or two about law.

However in the video he explains the lock was sent in by a viewer who committed "at least 4 felonies" including the theft of said lock. LPL explains he is in "receipt of stolen property" which is a crime and that he will be sending it immediately back to the sender.

That seems odd to me though, if you know you were given stolen property are you allowed to give it back to the thief to absolve yourself of any wrong doing?  Does he have no obligation to turn it into the police?

I don't know exactly where LPL lives but I believe Virginia.  No idea where the lock would have come from though.